# Bytecode manipulation on android at runtime

Tags: java, android, instrumentation

I wanted to know the reasons why  bytecode manipulation on android at runtime isn't possible? Is it because currently there are no supporting libraries for it or is it because the DEX format is something which cant be manipulated

Comment: [this](http://asm.ow2.org/doc/tutorial-asmdex.html) one?

Comment: Is this just a "I wonder why" or "I want to do something" question? If it's the latter you may be able to use Java-ASM. Doug is right in that you can't modify existing classes at runtime, however you can make your own classes and run those at runtime with ASM. I do this in a program of mine and while icky, works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At runtime, after a class has been loaded, the definition of that class can't be modified.  This is true for any JVM-like system, including Android's Dalvik.  However, you can modify classes *after compilation* but *before* inclusion into the APK, which I have done extensively for Android app tools.  After the APK is built, you can't make any changes, because the APK is signed to verify the contents of the archive.

Don't be confused with the similar technique in Objective-C called method swizzling which does allow you to effective make changes to object definitions at runtime.  The Objective-C runtime is mutable, the JVM runtime is not.

If you have an external dex that you want to modify before it's loaded into an Android app, you can do that as well, but again, once that classes have been loaded by a ClassLoader, they can't be modified.

Answer (score 3):

Well, there is [DexClassLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/dalvik/system/DexClassLoader.html), which can at least get classes from outside an apk. How you create the classes.dex inside that .jar is another story. To quote from the docs:

> A class loader that loads classes from .jar and .apk 
>   files containing a classes.dex entry. This can be used 
>   to execute code not installed as part of an application.
>
> This class loader requires an application-private, 
>   writable directory to cache optimized classes. 
>   Use Context.getCodeCacheDir() to create such a directory